# Appending user id to fetch data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am fetching data from an api and the api contains information about users with their name, userid and all that information. Now I am fetching the data from the api but I want to fetch data for a specific user only. Initially I want to display the name and a button to view more information about the person. But when the button is clicked I want to fetch all information about the user using user_id

```js
let table;
const show = (data) => {
  table.innerHTML = data
    .map(({id,name,email, gender,status}) => `<tr>
      <td colspan="3">${name} </td>
      <td><button class="more" data-id="${id}" data-name="${name}" data-email="${email}" data-gender="${gender}" data-status="${status}"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">visibility</span></button></td>
      <tr hidden><td>${email}</td>
      <td>${gender}</td>
      <td>${status}</td>
      </tr>`)
    .join("");
};
const load = () => {
  fetch("url")
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(show);
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  table = document.getElementById('table');
  table.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
    if (!tgt) return;
    const id = tgt.dataset.id;
    const name = tgt.dataset.name;
    const email = tgt.dataset.email;
    const gender = tgt.dataset.gender;
    const status = tgt.dataset.status;
    document.getElementById("modal-name").textContent = name;
    document.getElementById("modal-email").textContent = email;
    document.getElementById("modal-gender").textContent = gender;
    document.getElementById("modal-status").textContent = status;
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  })
  load();
});
```

Comment: Add a `click` listener on the `more` button. It can use `event.target.dataset.id` to get the user ID, and use this in another API call to fetch all the information about that user.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTES**

- Since you are using 2 different API calls, you don't need to add all the data to the button attribute.
- The following fetches a list of users and then renders their name and a button when the page loads. On button click, another api is called to get user information and it is then displayed in a dialog.

**HTML**

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Full Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<dialog id="dialog"></dialog>
```

**JS**

```js
const table = document.getElementById('table');
const dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    // fetch list of users
    const users = await fetch('/api/users')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .catch(error => (console.error(error), null));

    // return if no users or errors
    if ( !users ) return;
    
    // Count rows and stage data to be rendered
    let count = 0;
    const frag = new DocumentFragment();
    
    // loop over user data
    for (const user of users || []) {
        if ( !user ) continue;
        const { id, name } = user;

        // Create a table row
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `<td colspan="3">${name}</td>
            <td>
                <button onclick="fetchUserById(this)" class="more" data-id="${id}">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">visibility</span>
                </button>
            </td>`;

        // Add table row to staged data
        frag.appendChild(row);

        // render 10 rows at a time
        if (count > 0 && count % 10 == 0)
            table.appendChild(frag);
            
        count++;
    }
    
    // render remaining rows
    table.appendChild(frag);
});

async function fetchUserById( button ){
    // get id from button attribute
    const { id } = button.dataset || {};
    
    // fetch user data
    const user = await fetch(`/api/user/${id}`)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .catch(error => (console.error(error), null));
        
    // return if no users or errors
    if ( !user ) return;
    
    // Close the dialog if it was open
    dialog.close();

    // Render the data while dialog is closed
    dialog.innerHTML = `
        <span id="modal-name">${user.name}</span>
        <span id="modal-email">${user.email}</span>
        <span id="modal-gender">${user.gender}</span>
        <span id="modal-status">${user.status}</span>
        <span id="modal-other-info">${user.otherInfo}</span>
    `;

    // Open the dialog
    dialog.showModal();
}
```